# Sort on Nested Associations

Tags: entity-framework

My database

```
[ Departement ] *-* [ Group ] 1-* [ Room ]
```

A departement can have many groups (many - many) and a group can have many rooms

I want to return the `departement` with a specific id, get the `groups` order on group.name and get the `rooms` from the groups ordered by room.number

What I have so far

```
db.Departement .Include("Group.Room").ToList().First(a => a.Id == idDepartement);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to sort on the associations (group and room)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input `x` is an `IEnumerable<Department>` then:

```
x.SelectMany(d => d.Group).OrderBy(g => g.Name)
```

will result in an `IEnumerable<Group>` ordered by name (across all departments). [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618.aspx) takes a `Func<TIn, IEnumerable<TOut>>` and merges all the returned enumerables into a single enumerable; this allows you to follow the association from one or more starting objects to many associated objects.

> want to return the departement with a specific id[...]get the rooms from the groups ordered by room.number

Do you want the result to be a collection of departments, groups or rooms?

> `.ToList().`

That means you are getting all the Departments with all their groups and rooms from the Entity source and moving them into local memory before then throwing away most of the data (all not associated with the first returned department). Unless the data is rather small, it would be better to do that on the entity source (database server one assumes) rather than wasting time and bandwidth copying it locally.